# Which non premium RxDB RxStorage can be used as a database backend for GraphQL Replication on a NodeJS backend application?

Tags: graphql, rxdb

I'm studying RxDB to use it in a NodeJS backend with GraphQL replication but I couldn't find any free opensource RxStorage with this specs in the documentation.

- [PouchDB](https://rxdb.info/rx-storage-pouchdb.html) - seems to work only with CouchDB replication (no info about GraphQL in the docs)
- [Dexie.js](https://rxdb.info/rx-storage-dexie.html) uses IndexedDB which is browser based
- [LokiJS](https://rxdb.info/rx-storage-lokijs.html) also uses IndexedDB
- [Memory](https://rxdb.info/rx-storage-memory.html) (I'm looking for a persistent solution)
- [IndexedDB](https://rxdb.info/rx-storage-indexeddb.html) - browser based
- [SQLite](https://rxdb.info/rx-storage-sqlite.html) - premium
- [FoundationDB](https://rxdb.info/rx-storage-foundationdb.html) - premium

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FoundationDB storage is not part of the premium plugins. You can use that for free. The pouchdb storage does also work for the graphql replication.